# how to fetch all docouments with an ID that doesnt exist in the given array? (Cloud Firestore)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of IDs. Now, I would like to fetch all documents that DO NOT exist in that array.

Lets say `let array = ["id1", "id2", "id3];`

and document IDs in Firestore: *"id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"*.

So basically I need to fetch only the docs with "id4" and "id5";

I thought of using this but I am not sure how exactly:

```
const westCoastCities = citiesRef.where('regions', 'array-contains', 'west_coast').get();
```

I am new to Firebase so please be patient with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
idsRef.where('ids', 'not-in', ["id1", "id2", "id3]);
```

You should always check their doc first https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not-in